# How to display the generated results by the system in graph form

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

We are building a content management website for our thesis. Our site provides statistics about the overall crop production. The user can choose what locations and crops he wants to compare and the results will be displayed in table or in graph. We already did the table part. The problem is in displaying the results, it's not directly from the database. The system will generate first the results before displaying it. I attached some photos. enter image description here. We are new to web dev so please help me :(

[image]

In this photo, the barangays are being compared. The user chose the production of banana and lettuce. We want to convert the table data into graph.

Comment: saw this on internet [MYSQLI data to graph](https://www.dreamhost.com/blog/generating-charts-from-mysql-database-using-php/) seems easy to understand

Answer (score 0):

There are many libraries for plotting charts and graphs , you may search google for the same .

I have used 2 for the same till now :

```
https://www.highcharts.com/

http://www.chartjs.org/
```

Please go through both of them and see what fits your need .

Would be better to start with chart.js if you are new and then look for highcharts .

Hope this is helpful